# I cannot connect to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
import axios from 'axios';

const [errorList, setErrorList] = useState([]); 
    const [isloading, setIsloading] = useState(false); 
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        name: '',
        lastName: '',
        age: 0,
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        password: ''
    });

  async function submitRegisterForm(e) { 

        e.preventDefault(); 

        setIsloading(true); 

        let validationResult = validateRegisterForm();

        if (validationResult.error) {

            setErrorList(validationResult.error.details); 

            setIsloading(false); 
        }
        else {
            let  {data}= await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/user/signup', user );

            if (data.message === 'success') {
                setIsloading(false); 
                navigate('/login') 
            }
            else {
                setError(data.message); 

                setIsloading(false); 
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried this code and the result was:

AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
:
"ERR_NETWORK"
config
:
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
:
"Network Error"
name
:
"AxiosError"
request
:
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
stack
:
"AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:54571:14)"
[[Prototype]]
:
Error

I don't know what I did wrong even though I'm using the correct URL

Answer (score 0):

import axios from 'axios';

let navigate = useNavigate();

const [user, setUser] = useState({
name: '',
lastName: '',
age: 0,
email: '',
phone: '',
password: ''
});
async function submitRegisterForm(e) {

```
e.preventDefault(); 

setIsloading(true); 

let validationResult = validateRegisterForm();

if (validationResult.error) {

    setErrorList(validationResult.error.details); 

    setIsloading(false); 
}
else {
    let  {data}= await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/user/signup', user );

    if (data.message === 'success') {
        setIsloading(false); 
        navigate('/login') 
    }
    else {
        setError(data.message); 

        setIsloading(false); 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).